# How to use @JsonProperty to convert Snake Case?

Tags: json, rest, properties, entity

I have a Entity in Spring Boot REST app, I tried to convert property name from Camel Case to Snake Case and I used as below

```
@JsonProperty
private String createdBy;
```

but I can't get what I need in JSON naming as created_by, why? do I have to use @JsonProperty("created_by")? is there any default way to do?

Comment: I got answer to add "spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy= CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES" as below to application.properties

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your rest client as SNAKE_CASE (since jackson 2.7) or CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES (for older versions).

This solution work if whole comunication is SNAKE_CASE.

If your client is CAMEL_CASE and some responses are SNAKE_CASE you need to use @JsonPropery annotation on your class.

Using your example should be:

```
@JsonProperty("created_by")
private String createdBy;
```

You need to specify the snake case "variable" name on @JsonPropery  annotation